# Adding a specific styles to a gwt element

Tags: html, css, gwt

Is it possible to add a specific style to a gwt element??

e.g. if I have a button

```
  Button X= new Button("X");
```

now if i want the button to be italic

can i do something like that

X.addStyleName("font-style:italic");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The styleName is only valid for an style defined in your CSS file. Check the answer from hilal for more details about it.

If you only need to specify an specific value, you can do something like

```
DOM.setStyleAttribute(myButton.getElement(), "fontStyle", "italic");
```

keep in mind that then you're hard coding these value, and any change in the style will require to recompile your code.